# Assembler not finding second operand in MOV

Tags: arm, fedora-25

This is the file I am trying to assemble (filename: asmtut3.s):

```
.global _start
_start:
MOV R0, #20
MOV R7, #1
SWI 0
```

When I try to assemble it using:

```
as -o asmtut3.o asmtut3.s
```

I get the error:

```
asmtut3.s: Assembler messages:
asmtut3.s:3: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
asmtut3.s:4: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
asmtut3.s:5: Error: no such instruction: `swi 0'
```

I am running fedora 25, if that helps?

Comment: What does `as -V` print? What has this to do with vim?

Comment: you're probably not even using the right assembler, looks like X86 to me. MOV expects a register at the second argument (the # is a comment) and there's no SWI instruction.

Comment: Fo rclarification for AT&T x86 mov would expect a destination as a second operand not a constant. For arm this code is fine as pointed out you are likely using an assembler for some other instruction set.

Answer (score 1):

Use **arm-none-eabi-as** instead of **as**

```
arm-none-eabi-as -o asmtut3.o asmtut3.s
```